# Calling for layer in ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, layers, arcgis-pro

Every single example I see online, the code has the mapname.listLayers() in order to call the layer.

Don't we have a way to call the layer by its name instead? The reason I'm asking this is because this code does not work at all:

```
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
aprxMap = aprx.listMaps("Map")[0]
aprxMap.addDataFromPath(outfcname)    
install_layer = aprxMap.listLayers(installname)
layer_simbology = r"C:\ArcGIS\LAYER\symbologylayer.lyrx"
arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(install_layer, layer_simbology)
aprxMap.removeLayer(install_layer)
aprx.save()
```

The code does not update the symbol, neither remove the layer from the map. But add the Feature Class (outfcname) to map.

Comment: I'm having trouble following the code. You bring in "layer_simbology" to change the symbology of "install_layer", but then you remove "install_layer"? You might need to refresh the map after applying, or add it back to the map?

Comment: The removeLayer part was just for troubleshooting. I noticed that the Applysimbology is not working. So I added the removeLayer, and saw that the layer is not being removed as well. With that i got the conclusion that the issue is how I'm calling the layer.

Answer (score 3):

aprxMap.listLayers() will return a list even if there is only one layer that matches the wildcard you passed. You need to index the 0 position in the list before assigning it to install_layer.

```
install_layer = aprxMap.listLayers(installname)[0]
```